# Binary output instead of download dialog of a PDF file

Tags: php, download

Code below shows binary data instead of showing download dialog for a pdf file.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    header("Pragma: public"); 
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filepath)."\";" ); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath)); 
    readfile($filepath);
```

`exit`;

```
already tried application/pdf but no luck !
```

Comment: That should generally work. Have you tried with another browser?

Comment: Yes tried FF and Chrome

Comment: I'm not sure whether it'd help, but try to remove the "**;**" at the end of filename.

Comment: I just tried that and still the same output. It's weird as above code should've worked fine.

Comment: I've just tried your code with and w/o the ";" and it works as expected. It is deferentially an issue with your specific browsers.

Comment: It seems some server settings playing up.

Answer (score 1):

Replace **application/octet-stream** with **application/pdf** and try again.